# Descriptive statistics/summaries for scored questionnaire

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I'm collecting data in a questionnaire for facilities. The questionnaire is split into sections, and scores are aggregated (summed) per section. Relevant questions vary based on the kind of facility. What kinds of sensible group summaries can I generate from such data? Data is generally grouped by, say, town or city.

The questions in the questionnaire are mostly qualitative, for example, if a facility is publicly or privately held, or if a certain kind of equipment is available at the facility or not. Some of those questions have a score associated with the kind of response provided, for example 5 points if a certain equipment is available. The scores are summed per section.

I'm interested in providing useful summaries for data aggregated per region. For quantitative data, that's pretty straightforward - this is the mean number of doodads available in facilities in Bumpyville, for example. However, I'm less certain on how to summarize the other data. To further clarify, let's say that publicly held facilities can have a maximum score of 30 points in section C, and privately held facilities can have a maximum score of 26 points in the same section, what useful summaries can I generate for the data?

Comment: You'd need to be more specific about your goals in order to get useful answers. Also, knowing what specific data you're collecting would help.

Comment: @Patricio thanks for your comment. i've updated the question and hope it's clearer.